# Building bootable iso using mksisofs

Tags: powershell, iso

I'm trying to build bootable linux ISO under windows using mkisofs

this is the command I'm executing:

```
mkisofs -r -V “Modified Iso” -o D:\MOR.iso -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux\isolinux.bin -c isolinux\boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table D:\modified\iso\
```

the output is:

```
Uh oh, I cant find the boot image 'isolinux\isolinux.bin' inside the target tree.
```

the structure of the `D:\modified\iso\` folder is:

```
[BOOT]\
EFI\
images\
isolinux\
Packages\
repodata\
sbin\
.discinfo
.treeinfo
comps.xml
ks.cfg
```

Comment: This question really belongs on Server Fault:  http://serverfault.com/about

Comment: And is `isolinux.bin` inside the `isolinux` directory there? Does using `-b isolinux/isolinux.bin` work?

Comment: "yes, please have a look here http://serverfault.com/questions/715260/building-bootable-iso-using-mksisofs"
 isolinux\isolinux.bin or isolinux/isolinux.bin produce the same result

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps. Its working for me.
you need to add ks file.

1. List item
2. Create a directory to mount your source.

### mkdir /tmp/bootiso.

3. Loop mount the source ISO you are modifying. (Download from Red Hat / CentOS.)

### mount -o loop /path/to/some.iso /tmp/bootiso

4. Create a working directory for your customized media.

### mkdir /tmp/bootisoks

5. Copy the source media to the working directory.

### cp -r /tmp/bootiso/* /tmp/bootisoks/

6. Unmount the source ISO and remove the directory.

### umount /tmp/bootiso && rmdir /tmp/bootiso.

7. Change permissions on the working directory.

### chmod -R u+w /tmp/bootisoks

8. Copy your Kickstart script which has been modified for the packages and %post to the working directory.

### cp /path/to/someks.cfg /tmp/bootisoks/isolinux/ks.cfg

9. Copy any additional RPMs to the directory structure and update the metadata.

### cp /path/to/*.rpm /tmp/bootisoks/Packages/. cd /tmp/bootisoks/Packages && createrepo -dpo .. .

10. Add kickstart to boot options.

### sed -i 's/append\ initrd\=initrd.img$/append initrd=initrd.img\ ks\=cdrom:/ks.cfg/' /tmp/bootisoks/isolinux/isolinux.cfg

11. Create the new ISO file.

### cd /tmp/bootisoks && mkisofs -o /tmp/boot.iso -b isolinux.bin -c boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -V "CentOS 7 x86_64" -R -J -v -T isolinux/. .

12. Add an MD5 checksum (to allow testing of media).

### implantisomd5 /tmp/boot.iso

[Reference serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/517908/how-to-create-a-custom-iso-image-in-centos)
https://serverfault.com/questions/517908/how-to-create-a-custom-iso-image-in-centos